# Spring form with JQuery validation

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, jquery-validate, spring-webflow

I am trying to add jquery validations to an exisitng spring form.

The issue is in spring form if you have following

`<form:input size="60" path="contact.emailAddressTxt"/>`

The HTML generated is

```
<input id="contact.emailAddressTxt" type="text" size="60" value="" name="contact.emailAddressTxt">
```

If you observe the value for name and id gets genearated. In Jquery validate plugin when I try to set rules using the generated names, it fails to load. In Jquery I cannot use `contact.emailAddressTxt`

So how do I validate such input fields using jquery validate plugin?

Comment: what is that 'contact'? is it a modelattrribute value?

Comment: its a POJO which has the attribute emailAddressTxt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape character is \\ and not a single . The following code worked

```
$("#contact\\.emailAdressTxt")
```

Answer (score 2):

In jquery a dot is a special character so you need to escape it.

Try:
    $("#contact\.emailAdressTxt")

Else you can also use a class for each validation type. Like this you would not need to bind each input explicitly.

I'm not sure if you can control the way ids are generated in spring. In Jsf I've used underscores and this was easy with jquery. Probably you can do something similar.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, The escape character did not help. But I finally added the class and got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the I'd, even in spring:input tag

Comment: No, I tried overriding the name and id attributes but still in generated HTML I am observing that generated values is used and my validation rules are ignored

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form:input id="contactEmail" name="contactEmail" type="email" label="E-mail" size="60" path="contactEmail"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Jquery validate plugin when I try to set rules using the generated names, it fails to load.

You would simply surround the `name` with quotes.

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        "contact.emailAddressTxt": {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

[See documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)).